# How to get these two divs side-by-side?

Tags: css, layout, html

I have two divs that are not nested, one below the other. They are both within one parent div, and this parent div repeats itself. So essentially:

```
<div id='parent_div_1'>
  <div class='child_div_1'></div>
  <div class='child_div_2'></div>
</div>

<div id='parent_div_2'>
  <div class='child_div_1'></div>
  <div class='child_div_2'></div>
</div>

<div id='parent_div_3'>
  <div class='child_div_1'></div>
  <div class='child_div_2'></div>
</div>
```

I want to get each pair of `child_div_1` and `child_div_2` next to each other. How can I do this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```css
#parent_div_1, #parent_div_2, #parent_div_3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.child_div_1 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/c6242/1/

Comment: He wants the children div aligned next to one another, not the parents (at least that was my understanding...)

Comment: I still think `display: table-cell` will get results closer to what he means (since then they will have the same height etcetera) but this way will certainly work.

Comment: @ehdv `display: table-cell` is not supported in IE6 IE7. float:left; is the proper way to do this.

Comment: Actually the proper way to do this in IE6,7 is with `<tr><td>`, because any other option will break when the user resizes the window.  In modern browsers, `display: inline-block` is usually the best option.

Answer (score 148):

Since div's by default are [`block`](http://learnlayout.com/display.html) elements - meaning they will occupy full available width, try using -

```
display:inline-block;
```

The `div` is now rendered inline i.e. does not disrupt flow of elements, but will still be treated as a block element.

I find this technique easier than wrestling with `float`s.

See this tutorial for more - http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html. I would recommend even the previous articles that lead up to that one. (No, I did not write it)

Comment: I really liked this solution. My only problem with it is that is aligns the bottom of both divs instead of aligning the top. Is there a quick setting for this too?

Comment: I would suggest using 2 wrapper `div`s having equal height so then the content inside them would seem to appear top-aligned.

Comment: I agree. This is much better than `float:left` because it gives you so many more options without redefining your entire layout. Things "just work" this way. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/SrAQd/4

Comment: In order to get vertical alignment I'd add "vertical-align: top;"

Comment: @Chris: Yes, I agree with cdiggins. That should help you.

Answer (score 56):

I found the below code very useful, it might help anyone who comes searching here

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background-color: green; float:left;">-</div>
    <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background-color: blue; float:right;">-</div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50%; background-color: red; clear:both">-</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 16):

Using flexbox it is super simple!

```
#parent_div_1, #parent_div_2, #parent_div_3 {
    display: flex;
}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fu5aoo7a/)

Answer (score 6):

Using the style

```
.child_div_1 {
    float:left
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Best that works for me:

```
 .left{
   width:140px;
   float:left;
   height:100%;
 }

 .right{
   margin-left:140px;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jiantongc/7uVNN/

Answer (score 3):

Using flexbox

```
   #parent_div_1{
     display:flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

User `float:left` property in child div class

check for div structure in detail : http://www.dzone.com/links/r/div_table.html

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex;` is the solution.

use

```
.header {
    display: flex;
}
```

for this code:

```
    <div className="header">
      <div className="logo-container">
        <img
          className="logo"
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/3c/b2/4f/3cb24f7d0defcb91eb51b091325d5f47.jpg"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About Us</li>
          <li>Contact Us</li>
          <li>Cart</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`logo-container` and `nav-items` will be shown side to side.