# how to make Two div in a line when down one height raise, up one auto smaller

Tags: html, css

my code:

```
<div>
    <div class='a'> </div>
    <footer></footer> 
</div>
```

a:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0px;
height: 105px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
background: #f5f5f5;
border-top: solid 1px #afafb6;
z-index: 900;
```

footer:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
background: #F0EEEE;
white-space: nowrap;
```

it's like this:

```
-----|---------|
|   ||         |
| a ||         |
-----|         |
|   ||         |
|foo||         |
|ter||         |
-----|---------|
```

when footer height bigger,how to make div a's height auto smaller.

I tought a way to set footer max-height to 60% ,and a to 40%,but if footer changes ,60% became a bit small

Comment: I reproduced your code into a fiddle, but it doesnt give me the same result as your 'drawing'. Anyway; why not give the wrapper a height of 100% and the footer for example 60%. the a will size to 40%.

Comment: Use JS/jQuery to calculate appropriate height.

Comment: well, about getting divs side-by-side please have a look at this link:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387392/how-to-get-these-two-divs-side-by-side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387392/how-to-get-these-two-divs-side-by-side)

Comment: @Justinas thanks,I write js to get the foorter's height and set the a div's bottom to the height

Answer (score 0):

You can use **css tables** to do this.

**[FIDDLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9sx2o9oq/1/)** and **[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9sx2o9oq/3/)**

Also, you can add a `max-height` for the footer by wrapping the content in an additional element and setting max-height on that element.

**[FIDDLE 3](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9sx2o9oq/4/)** (Be sure to resize the browser window)

### Demo

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: yellow;
}
.wpr {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.a, footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    display:table-row;
}
.a {
    background: pink;
    height:100%;
}
p {
    max-height: 40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
    <div class='a'>a</div>
    <footer>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```