# Inline divs: shrink-wrap one, hide overflow on the other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an interesting challenge in making two inline text elements behave in a particular way. Here are my parameters:

- The *main text* on the left will vary in width, from about 30-60% of the parent width.
- The *supplementary text* on the right will vary drastically from 20-120% of the parent width.
- Parent width is responsive-ish and can shrink to 75% of its full width. Absolute positioning won't do.
- Whenever both items don't fit, I want *MAIN TEXT* to remain fully visible (no ellipsis) and *supplementary text* to hide the overflow:

  - overflow: hidden
  - text-overflow: ellipsis

Both the CSS and HTML are completely available for modification, though I'd prefer if the HTML remained semantic. Feel free to use JS/jQuery if there's a nice way of doing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gksfwozz/1/

```css
.outer {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    border: 3px solid skyblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.left {
    background-color: salmon;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.right {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="left">
        MAIN TEXT
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        additional info sdjkfhsdf 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your css a little bit. here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gksfwozz/4/)

for .left I added  float and max-width (as you sait it's up to 60% of the container) and I removed the overflow:hidden cause you want it fully always.

```
.left {
 background-color: salmon;
 white-space: nowrap;
 max-width: 60%;
 float: left;
}
```

and I remove the display:flex from .outter. I think it is what you want.

Comment: Very good! It does answer my question, though your slight modifications weren't what I was looking for. However, they're neither your fault nor relevant. Thanks for solving my problem! I'll give the answer to the other guy for answering 2 minutes before you :(

Comment: it's ok,the important thing is you get what you wantet.but I was answer 2 mins before the other guy ! ;) right now my answer was answered 16 mins ago but his answer was answered 14 mins ago so I was first.but anyway ! @jonas.ninja ;)

Comment: Right you are! I got my numbers confused. Awarded to you!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.outer {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    border: 3px solid skyblue;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    background-color: salmon;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.right {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
What I have:
<div class="outer">
    <div class="left">
        MSGDFGDFGDFDFGDFGDFGDFG
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        adfhdfgh
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gksfwozz/2/

from this link [How to get these two divs side-by-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387392/how-to-get-these-two-divs-side-by-side)

Comment: Excellent! Your embedded code doesn't seem to work very well, but the JSfiddle you linked doe the trick. Interesting to note that your answer is almost identical to the other guy's.