# Displaying image in align to login form using materializecss

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

[image: Updated screenshot]

[image: Login and image]

You can see the entire code here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjqxOq

I have created a login page using materializecss and now i want to display a image in alignment to login form. But when I try to do it displays one above the other as displayed in screenshot.

Also I did make some changes like I added class="right align" to image due to which image moved right side but i was unable to move login form up in line with image.

```
   <div>
    <img src="images/one.png" height="480" width="580">
   </div>

   <div id="login-page" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 z-depth-6 card-panel">
     <form class="login-form">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s12 center">
         <h3 class="left login-form-text">Login</h3>
       </div>
     </div>

    <div class="row margin">
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <i class="mdi-social-person-outline prefix"></i>
         <input class="validate" id="email" type="email" >
          <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" class="center-align">Email</label>
      </div>
     </div>

    <div class="row margin">
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
         <input id="password" type="password" >
         <label for="password">Password</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">         
      <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12  login-text">
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" />
          <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s1">
        <a href="" class="btn waves-effect waves-light grey darken-2 col s12">Login</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to put the list around the div's containing the form and image, and that will be difficult due to the complexity of your project...How about this post here? [How to get these two divs side-by-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387392/how-to-get-these-two-divs-side-by-side) Would that work?

Comment: Thank you for the efforts. There is definitely some improvement but not completely successfull. Login form was moved up and image to right side but login form got clumsy. I dont see their input field like before only names and also login and register buttons could be seen a part of it.

Comment: What do you mean by clumsy?

Comment: I believe there is also something to do with native classes of materializecss

Comment: Did you set a width for the form?

Comment: It looks like the background is smaller then the text/input

Comment: It looks as though you need to set a width.

Comment: You are bang on target Jeff. Its perfect now. but it has lost its responsiveness as played with framework. but any quick tricks to solve this?

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the efforts and time you invested in helping me out.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped!  Not sure what you mean as I haven't used frameworks yet!  Good luck! What is the website URL you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "and now i want to display a image in alignment to login form.", do you mean you want the picture to the right and the form to the left?

If so, and the form and image are the only things on the page, did you try putting the form and the image in an HTML list, and in CSS setting the list to

```css
display: inline-block;
```

?

The from would need to be first (left side) and the pictures second (right side).

Not sure if this helps but good luck!

Comment: Yes what you thought is right but how to put a login form in a list as it has so many classes and tags. If you see the codepen you will get an idea.