# How to place two div side-by-side in a HTML page

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple HTML page, where I have a parent `div` with over-flow enabled in both axes. Now within that `div`, there are 2 `div`s which I want to place side by side.

```css
#Result {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .02);
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 99%;
  height: calc(100% - 90px - 70px);
  position: absolute;
}

#Left,
#Right {
  height: calc(99vh - 90px - 70px);
  width: 28vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
  border-right: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
}

#Right {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-right: 0px solid #737373;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id='Result'>
  <div id='Left'>

  </div>
  <div id='Right'>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Codepen -** https://codepen.io/Volabos/pen/qBdNyPa?editors=1100

However unfortunately, the 3rd `div` is moved down if its width is taken a large number. How can I place the 2nd and 3rd `div` side by side?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get these two divs side-by-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387392/how-to-get-these-two-divs-side-by-side)

Comment: they are actually placed side by side if they fit. what do you want to happen if they dont fit? do you want horizontal scrolling on overflow? then overflow-x:auto might be your friend.

Comment: @Michriko - overflow-x:auto  is not solving my problem. Yes, you are right saying that if it doesnt fit then there should be horizontal scroll-bar

Comment: try `display:flex;`  inside Result div css

Comment: @Rkv88-Kanyan - display:flex; is removing the scroll bar

Comment: oh sure, not seen you already used overflow. As many other also recommended, flex is a good way to manage alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may safely use for the parent `display:flex` + `overflow:auto` and for the children `flex-shrink:0` or `min-width:xx`

Possible example

```css
#Result {
  display: flex;  /* flex model */
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;  /* whatever or min-height or let grow from content  */
}

#Right,
#Left {
  flex-shrink: 0;  /* do not allow childd to shrink and allow overflow  */
}

#Left {
  width: 28vw;  /* whatever */
}

#Right {
  width: 100vw;  /* whatever */
}

/* demo purpose */

div div {
  border: solid;
}

#Left {
  background: lightblue;
}

#Right {
  background: lightgreen;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id='Result'>
  <div id='Left'>

  </div>
  <div id='Right'>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Floats can be a way, but I'd rather go with flexbox:

```
#result {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between  // or flex-start, center, flex-end ... whatever
}
```

Your #Left and #Right will be placed side by side and will have the same height by default.

EDIT: Container with two children aligned next to each other, including a horizontal scrollbar:

```
  <style>

  .container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }

  .child {
    width: 60%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

</style>


<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this approach, horizontal scroll bar vanishes

Comment: Well, yes ... but what's the point in a horizontal scrollbar? I always try to avoid that at all costs ...

But ok, if you have to have that scrollbar, apply 'flex-shrink: 0' to #Left and 'right. Since both have a defined width, they will overflow #result at some point

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">1</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">2</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 8">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome, can you explain what is the idea ?

Comment: With this way you can keep all divs side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:left;` and `clear:right;`

https://codepen.io/osmanraifgunes/pen/PoqzByB?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you don't mind bodging it a little bit:

```css
#left {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#right {
  /* Change this to whatever the width of your left column is*/
  margin-left: 215px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <p>foo</p>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <p>bar</p>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
```